Op-amp schematic microphone connection questions
Looking at the schematic of the X-NUCLEO-AMICAM1, I’m trying to understand why a quad op-amp is used for two microphones. Why isn’t there a single input and output for each microphone? What is this configuration called, and what are the advantages of using it?
I’d really appreciate any insights or explanations!


ST probably doesn’t have anyone with experience overseeing these documentation releases. The schematic is awful. I’m not sure what could be done to make it worse - maybe if it was a 10th generation analog Xerox copy… Yes, back in the days of blizzards and uphill-only roads, documents were copied with laser printers without the laser. In place of laser mirror assy they had optical paper imager, ha! :)

this is a fine question. any users want to comment on why they downvoted?

@rohmeooo i agree and there are silent critics that rarely justify their negative bias.

I think the circuit is not very well drawn as it takes too long to see which signal goes where and why. The worst issue is the opamp chip is drawn as a black box with 14 pins, so you have to decipher how it would look like if the op-amps were drawn as separate 3-pin op-amp symbols.
The mic signal is first amplified with a non-inverting op-amp cirvuit, with gain of 1+(56k/2k)=29, or 29dB, and them fed to ADC positive pin.
That positive signal is also taken into an inverting op-amp circuit to invert it with gain of 10k/10k, or 0dB, and fed to ADC negative pin.
Basically the mic signal is converted into two signals that are (a) differential, (b) balanced, and (c) also symmetric for the ADC input, because that's how the ADC input wants the signal.
Basically that's what goes around in XLR audio cables between audio gear.
In reality the terms are used quite liberally, but each term means a specific thing in the system.

It's so much clearer now, I didn't even know what to search for before.
thank you !

Can you explain what the differences in differential, balanced, and symmetric are?

@rohmeooo I could, but they are new questions. You could ask them as new questions, but they are likely answered already, or for least effort, even Wikipedia should explain them.

The MEMs is single ended and the amp is also single-ended, and not differential but it is relative to COMM not shown but expected to be Vdd/2.  Pls correct your accepted answer

@D.A.S. The amplifiers convert a single-ended ground referenced signal to balanced and differential signal, so the differential ADC can get a large enough differential signal. The audio is AC coupled into ADC input anyway so it makes no difference if it is differential relative to VDD/2 as ADC biases it's own input. RS-485, CAN, LVDS, CML and USB are also differential signals, that revolve around some non-zero common mode offset. So offset does not need to be zero for a differential signal. Thus I think there is nothing to correct in my answer.

I understand you but there is another reason for inverting and that signal is not used elsewhere than to create stable negative feedback to microphonics, otherwise if not on the same board is not needed. Thus not intended to be balanced nor differential but rather just inverting high Z  gain in 2 stages. Ok?

@D.A.S. You are looking at a cropped circuit schematic. The amplified and inverted signals both go to an AD1974 audio ADC with 1.9Vrms differential input using a single 3.3V supply voltage.

Thanks now I see better with a faster iOS now

Basically what you have is this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
It's a non-inverting amplifier with a gain of
$$
\frac{56k}{2k}+1 = 29
$$
followed by a unity gain inverting amplifier, this gives two outputs 180° out of phase, which turns the single ended signal from the microphone into a differential signal to drive the ADC inputs shown on page 3 of the datasheet available here.

Thank you, this really helps.

@AmitAflalo I can see why you were having trouble with it, that original schematic looks like it was drawn by a committee.

Good answer but balanced? (?) It is inverted to avoid parasitic positive feedback with high Z +input on the front end. That's critical with High Z and high gain with microphonics (piezoelectric mechanical vibration signals)

@D.A.S. The output is not single ended, you can see in the datasheet that the DAC inputs are configured as differential and driven by Mx+ and Mx-. I've updated my answer to include this.

Thanks. Right I could not see that from the info provided and my iOS beta update was slagging my response time to open tabs until I rebooted.  That's not an isolated case. Differential would be the best way to remove offsets and Feedback.

Balanced but with the skew of 1 opamp delay and a BW of 8000kHz/29 !

The MEMS mic requires AC coupling to high R load and inverting gain to avoid positive feedback from high output knocks that with piezo microphonics cause a parasitic high audio frequency resonance.
MP23ABS1 https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/mp23abs1.pdf
High performance MEMS audio sensor single ended analog bottom-port microphone.
The MP23ABS1 has an acoustic overload point of 130 dBSPL with a typical 64 dB signal-to-noise ratio.
The sensitivity of the MP23ABS1 is -38 dBV ±1 dB @ 94 dBSPL, 1 kHz
Thus a good solution to maximize SNR at a level of 94 dBSPL 1kHz is generate near 1V with 39 dB gain biased at Vdd/2=COMM on -38 dBV+/-1 means the minimum output is 0 dBV =1V
To allow the use of just about any Op Amp bias current and avoid excessively high R values that might be affected by parasitic capacitance, R=56k is the load with Zin+ is high with series 1uF rolls off near 30 Hz.
So why does the datasheet recommend and inverting amp. with gain? Why does this board uses a 56k termination to a source MEMs with 2 stages 39 dB and -1 ?
Many reasons: #1 stable SNR to parasitic feedback for phase array beam forming microphones.
